# regex match ONLY the first occurence of a character with R

Tags: r, regex

I want to match only the first occurence of a character. Intuitively, this should be a really easy expression but all solutions I can find match UNTIL the first occurence.

Example:

```
test / hello / abc
```

I want to match only the first "/".

### Edit:

I am using R. Regex solutions that work with groups, like `(^.*?)\K\/`, do not seem to work.

Comment: What language are you using? You might be better served by using something like "indexOf", rather than Regex.

Comment: `^[^/]*\K/` or `^.*?\K/` will do. "do not seem to work" - they work, just use the PCRE engine (`perl=TRUE` with base R regex functions). If you have a more concrete question please show how you are using the regex and provide some test case to see what you are after.

Comment: Yes, Wiktor's answer solved it.

Comment: Well, it is the deleted `user2705585` user's answer :).